# Using pgfmath declared function in pgfplots/tikz commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

The commented rows of the following code give me errors. It seems that functions declared with `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` do not work with `tikz` commands...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myfunct}{3}{\pgfmathparse{#1+#2*#3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {myfunct(1,2,x)};
%   \node at (axis cs:2,{myfunct(1,2,2)}) {aaa};
%   \draw (axis cs:2,{myfunct(1,2,2)}) -- (axis cs:0,5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A way to fix this would be to define a macro like:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\mymacro{myfunct(1,2,2)}
```

and use `\mymacro` instead of `myfunct(1,2,2)` but I would like to know if there is a way for using directly `myfunct(1,2,2)` avoiding the macro definition.

Comment: An unrelated tip: You can also use `\tikzset{declare function={myfunc{\a,\b,\c}=\a+\b+\c;}}` which has the advantage that you can use descriptive macro names and that `\a`, `\b` and `\c` are already evaluated so you do not worry about adding parentheses around `#1` and so on (in your case mathematically irrelevant, but still).

Comment: Should it be parentheses after the function handle, ie, `\tikzset{declare function={myfunc(\a,\b,\c)=\a+\b+\c;}}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you experience is caused by the fact that pgfplots up to and including version 1.8 applies no expression parsing to `axis cs`. In other words: it expect(ed) pure numbers like `42`, but not `2^2`.

This means that your math function is correct, and it would work in any pure tikz operations (`axis cs` is an add-on of pgfplots).

This has been improved for the current pgfplots stable 1.9: now, `axis cs` accepts math expressions. Note that version 1.9 is not one week old at the time of this writing, so it may take some time for MikTeX etc to pick it up. Upgrading pgfplots will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, so no way of doing it with older versions of `pgfplots`.. I will update it